# sqeeze buttons in one row using twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grails, gsp

I am adding button (set of alphabets) in one row. When I resize window it split that buttons in two row. I want all these button in one row. Here is my code.

```
<g:each in="${[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ]}" var="alphabet">
    <g:link controller="controller" action="action" class="btnForSearchAlphabet">
        ${alphabet}
    </g:link>
</g:each>
```

css is here:

```
.btnForSearchAlphabet {
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
padding: 4px 12px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
*margin-left: .3em;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #96989e;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
*border: 0;
border-color: #4C515D #4C515D #bfbfbf;
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
*zoom: 1;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

I want that all alphabet should in one row after re-sizing window.

**Before Re-sizing**

[image: before Re-sizing]

**After Re-Sizing**

[image: After Re-sizing]

Answer (score 1):

Add `white-space:nowrap` property for the parent element of button.

Here is the sample code.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="test">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <button>6</button>
    <button>7</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>9</button>
    <button>10</button>
    <button>11</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
button{
background:#ff00ff;
padding:10px;
}
.test{white-space:nowrap}
```

[**Sample DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bDTeH/)

Comment: Hi @Suresh, Thanks for you response. When I run demo it show button in one row but create a horizontal scroll. I wanted a responsive buttons which adjust its width and height accordingly.

Comment: In that case you need to give everything in percentage or em format. But it will reduce some levels, not all the levels. because it should show atleaset some text. check this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bDTeH/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need the **btn-toolbar** class , usage is as below

```
 <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
    <button class="btn btn-info">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info">Button 2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info">Button 3</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info">Button 4</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info">Button 5</button>
</div>
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/quyuj/1/